# How to wrap around a string in python

Tags: python, string

So I'm trying to make my own version of the ROT13 Cipher, and I want to wrap around a string to the next character.

```py
string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
# 'u' to 'h' and 'a' to 'n'
```

If the character was 'u' for example how would I get the character 13 steps in front of it? 
Which would end up to be 'h'.

I didn't know what to look up because i'm not great with words and explaining things.

Comment: take a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-find-python/#targetText=Python%20String%20%7C%20find()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator, known as `%`. The result it gives you is the remainder of the division of both numbers.

For example, 5%10 is 5, and 18%10 is 8.

You find the character's position:

```
pos = string.find('u')
```

You move it forward:

```
pos += 13
```

You find the corrected position:

```
pos %= len(string)
```

and then you print it:

```
print(string[pos])
```

Of course, you can write it more concisely:

```
print(string[(string.find('u')+13)%len(string)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps are:

1) Identify the index of 'u'

```
alphabet =  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'  
index_of_u = alphabet.index('u')
```

2) Use the modulo operator to calculate:

```
offset_index = (index_of_u + 13) % 27
```

3) Look up target

```
target_char = alphabet[offset_index]
```

Comment: Couldn't you make the same point about hard-coding the alphabet itself? I'm not trying to provide an industrial-grade ROT13 implementation, I'm just providing an example.

Comment: To truly future-proof, `from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet` :-)

Answer (score 0):

It could be done using slices of the alphabet to create a lookup dictionary.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
s = ascii_lowercase

rot13 = dict(zip(s, s[13:]+s[:13]))

>>> rot13
{'a': 'n', 'b': 'o', 'c': 'p', 'd': 'q', 'e': 'r', 'f': 's', 'g': 't', 'h': 'u', 'i': 'v', 'j': 'w', 'k': 'x', 'l': 'y', 'm': 'z', 'n': 'a', 'o': 'b', 'p': 'c', 'q': 'd', 'r': 'e', 's': 'f', 't': 'g', 'u': 'h', 'v': 'i', 'w': 'j', 'x': 'k', 'y': 'l', 'z': 'm'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a canonical answer, just use the builtins:

```
import codecs
codecs.encode('Canonical Answer', 'rot_13')
'Pnabavpny Nafjre'
```

For a handcrafted speedy version, @Chris Charley's answer is fine.

If you want something more generic, you can do.

```py
def rotN(n):
    start, end = map(ord, 'az')
    mod = end - start + 1
    def rot(char):
        return chr((ord(char) - start + n) % mod + start)
    return rot
```

then for example, `rot13 = rotN(13)` gives you a translator, and `rot13('u') == 'h'`.  Note that this still only works for lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to use the [ascii values](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65117-converting-between-ascii-numbers-and-characters/) of the characters.

```
def rot13_encrypt(text):
    return ''.join(chr((ord(letter) - ord('a') + 13) % 26 + ord('a')) for letter in text)
def rot13_decrypt(text):
    return ''.join(chr((ord(letter) - ord('a') - 13 + 26) % 26 + ord('a')) for letter in text)
rot13_encrypt('helloworld')
Out[22]: 'uryybjbeyq'
rot13_decrypt(rot13_encrypt('helloworld'))
Out[23]: 'helloworld'
```